# Need help to verify my working

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Working through ode, just needed someone to help me check whether the solution manual is correct. It says that $x_2$ dne if $a=0$ but my working seems to suggest that $x_2=t$ is a valid solution. I am guessing it treated the case $a>0$ and $a=0$ together which lead it to the wrong answer unless my working is wrong.

I am specifically solving the 2nd ivp with the case a=0.

The given differential equation, after setting $a = 0$, becomes:

$$
x'' - 0^2x = 0 \quad \text{(1)}
$$

Simplifying further, we have:

$$
x'' = 0 \quad \text{(2)}
$$

Equation (2) represents a differential equation with constant coefficients. The general solution to this equation is a linear function of the form $x(t) = c_1 t + c_2$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants to be determined.

To find the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ that satisfy the initial value problem (IVP) $x(0) = 0$ and $x'(0) = 1$, we can substitute these values into the general solution and solve for the constants.

Given $x(0) = 0$:
$$
0 = c_1 (0) + c_2
$$
$$
0 = c_2
$$

Given $x'(0) = 1$:
$$
1 = c_1
$$
$$
c_1 = 1
$$

Therefore, the solution to the initial value problem is:

$$
x(t) = t
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mistake imo. I think the book forgot to consider the case $a=0$ properly. The method applied was to use the characteristic equation which only produces the result described when the roots of the polynomial associated are distinct, this is clearly not the case when $a=0$.

The polynomial associated to the equation $x''=0$ is $x^2=0$ with solutions $r_1=r_2=0$. This case we simply have $y=(c_1+c_2x)e^{r_1x}$ as the general solution. Using that $r_1=0$ we obtain $y=c_1+c_2x$ and your reasoning is sound.

However, when $r_1\neq r_2$ we have a solution in the form $y=c_1e^{r_1x}
+c_2e^{r_2x}$ and since this was the only case considered in the solution, we found the mistake.

Comment: There's two IVP in the problem, I'm solving the 2nd for x2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification